# htaccess rewrite - Hide subfolder from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

We have a page file here:

```
ourdomain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/
```

But we'd like people to be able to access it by going here:

```
ourdomain.com/subfolder2/
```

So we need both a redirect and a rewrite.

Any idea how this can be achieved using htaccess? I've tried a million things and nothing is properly rewriting/redirecting.

What I currently have...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfolder1/subfolder2/?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.ourdomain.com/subfolder2/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ok, if people go to ourdomain.com/subfolder1/ only , they should also redirected or only when they request ourdomain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# Redirect from /subfolder1/subfolder2/...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subfolder1/(subfolder2/[^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite to /subfolder1/subfolder2/...
RewriteRule ^(subfolder2/.*) /subfolder1/$1 [NC,L]
```